# ashx file download, causing problem in firefox

Tags: .net, asp.net, ashx

Created a ashx page, which is called like

```
<a href="AttachmentHandler.ashx?id=2">download</a>
```

On IE it is working fine, but on firefox for some type of file(doc/xslx etc) it currupt the file, like change in size. i tried to use encodeing/charset options but it is not working

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="AttachmentHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;


public class AttachmentHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string attachmentId = context.Request["Id"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentId))
            {
                Attachment attachmentEntity = AttachmentProvider.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(attachmentId));
                if (attachmentEntity != null)
                {
                    context.Response.Clear();
                    //context.Response.ClearHeaders();

                    //context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    //context.Response.Charset = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.WebName;

                    //context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                    context.Response.Buffer = false;
                    context.Response.ContentType = attachmentEntity.AttachmentType;
                    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + attachmentEntity.Name + "\"");
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(attachmentEntity.AttachmentFile);
                    context.Response.Flush();
                    context.Response.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write(Resources.GlobalResource.ErrorMessageUnableAttachements);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IQity.Fusion.Utility.LoggingUtility.IQityErrorLogger.HandleException(ex);
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write(Resources.GlobalResource.ErrorMessageUnableAttachements);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Identified the problem, this is due to request header in Firefox while on IE it uses no compression
Firefox Request header:
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
If we change Firefox browser setting using about:config, than it start working.
Still not sure about the solution

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
context.Response.ContentType
```

in your this code and ur error will resolved...

```
if (attachmentEntity != null)
            {
                context.Response.Clear();
                //context.Response.ClearHeaders();

                //context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                //context.Response.Charset = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.WebName;

                //context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                context.Response.Buffer = false;
                context.Response.ContentType = attachmentEntity.AttachmentType;
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + attachmentEntity.Name + "\"");
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(attachmentEntity.AttachmentFile);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.Close();
            }
```

Comment: context.Response.ContentType is already being used, while upload we save mime and while downloading assign context.Response.ContentType to that mime, that is correct

Comment: ContentType is application/msword, for which file get currupted

Comment: I tried fiddler to check response from IE vs FF, IE uses Transfer-Encoding: chunked and FF uses IE uses Content-Encoding: gzip

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to call this: `context.Response.Close();`

Comment: i will try, actually the last few bytes are currupted or truncketed off, may be this coule be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had to code something similar :

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = attachmentEntity.AttachmentType;
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + attachmentEntity.Name + "\"");
context.Response.BinaryWrite(attachmentEntity.AttachmentFile);
context.Response.End();
```

and it works with FF... 
maybe the `.Flush()` is closing the stream a little too earlier...

One other thing I noticed : I use a piece of code to tell what is the ContentType.. and for Msword, I get `application/unknown`
but seems to work fine anyway..

Answer (score 0):

`.docx` is not `application/msword`.  It's `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`.

Check you're using the right MIME type for .docX and .xslX files.

Comment: it is correct, i am using doc=application/msword and docx=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document. problem comes even than

Comment: What problem?  You didn't give any details about the problem or results you are seeing in your question.